# Создание bat файла с переменной Python

Tags: python, tkinter, bat, переменные, ссылка

Не могу понять как сделать так чтобы ready_proj вставлялась в код bat Файла в "".
А то Python думает что это уже просто текст в "", а не переменная.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *


def browse_button():
    global folder_path
    ready_proj = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path.set(ready_proj)
    print(ready_proj)
    my_file = open("Test.bat", "w+")
    my_file.write("@Echo Off robocopy /s"  + ready_proj +  "d:/project" "*.prproj *.xml *.pkf *extracted* *drift* Pause")

root = Tk()
root.title("Name")
root.geometry ("400x150")

folder_path = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=folder_path)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)

button2 = Button(text="Проект", command=browse_button)
button2.grid(row=0, column=3)


mainloop()**
```

В итоге нужно чтобы код bat файла выглядел так

```
@Echo Off
robocopy /s "ссылка с python" "d:/project" *.prproj *.xml *.pkf *extracted* *drift*
Pause
```

Comment: Как нужно понятно. А как выглядит сейчас?

Comment: Сейчас в bat просто ссылка без "" по сторонам.

Answer (score 1):

Так работает:

```
my_file.write("@Echo Off robocopy /s" + "\"" + ready_proj + "\"" + "d:/project" "*.prproj *.xml *.pkf *extracted* *drift* Pause")
```